# Project Template Missing in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015

When i am try to create the Web application in Visual Studio 2015, i found many project template's those are present in Visual Studio 2013 are missing in this VS2015. I did reinstalling of VS2015 again, but after reinstalling also i am unable view those project template. Can any one please help me and give me some idea. Following is the screen shot of missing project template of Visual Studio 2015(https://i.stack.imgur.com/77tHX.png) and screen shot of project template of VS2013 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuSYC.png)

Comment: i think you opened or only installed "Microsoft Blend For Visual Studio" rather than VS2015.

Comment: i did installing directly by running vs_professional.exe